# Vaadin Router Error Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: [Vaadin.Router] Expected router outlet to be a valid DOM Node (but got null)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vaadin, router

I am using **Vaadin Router in my vue application**. 
Below is example what i am trying :
Below is my **App.vue**

```
<template>

      <HelloWorld/>

</template>

<script>

import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld';


export default {
  name: 'App',

  components: {
     HelloWorld,
  }
};
</script>
```

and below is my **HelloWorld.vue** :

```
<template>

      <div id = "outlet"></div>

</template>

<script>


import {Router} from '@vaadin/router';

const router = new Router(document.getElementById('outlet'));

router.setRoutes([
  {path: '/', component: 'my-web-component-a'},
  {path: '/other', component: 'my-web-component-other'}
]);
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',

};
</script>
```

I added scripts of my webcomponents inside this application's **index.html** like below :

```
<script src = "../assets/my-web-component-a.js"></script>
<script src = "../assets/my-web-component-other.js"></script>
```

But when i am starting my vue application, it is started but not rendering the web components and throwing following error :

```
vaadin-router.js?7629:2007 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: [Vaadin.Router] Expected router outlet to be a valid DOM Node (but got null)
    at Router.__ensureOutlet (vaadin-router.js?7629:2007)
    at Router.__addAppearingContent (vaadin-router.js?7629:2041)
    at eval (vaadin-router.js?7629:1783)
```

am i doing something wrong? i am not much familier with the **Vaadin**

Answer (score 0):

its possible that the "outlet" is located into the shadow dom, webcomponent encapsulate the elements. So, instead of `document.getElementById('outlet')` you could code the next line `this.shadowRoot.getElementById('outlet')`